# List ADT - How to free a struct pointer and its member?

Tags: c, pointers, free, heap-memory

Below is a `List` ADT,

```
typedef struct List{
  void **array;

  /* Following members for Housekeeping - Array enhancement*/
  int lastItemPosition;
  int size;
}List;
#define INITIAL_LIST_SIZE 50
```

---

`createList` operation tries to `free(*(list->array))` expecting to just free the array of `void*` but not the objects pointed to each `void*` because `listPointer` takes shallow copy of `list`

```
List *createList(List *list, Op opType){

  List *listPointer = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List));
  void *accumulator = NULL;
  if(opType == CREATE_NEW_LIST){

    accumulator = malloc(INITIAL_LIST_SIZE*sizeof(void*));
    listPointer->array = &accumulator;

    /* Is it safe to initialise zero to  element of array of void* pointers? */
    listPointer->array = memset(listPointer->array, 0, INITIAL_LIST_SIZE*sizeof(void *));

    listPointer->lastItemPosition = -1;
    listPointer->size = INITIAL_LIST_SIZE;
  }else if(opType == DOUBLE_THE_LIST){

    accumulator = malloc(2*(list->size)*sizeof(void *));
    listPointer->array = &accumulator;

    /* Performing shallow copy, Is deep copy required? */
    listPointer->array = memcpy(listPointer->array, list->array, list->size*sizeof(void*));

    listPointer->lastItemPosition = list->lastItemPosition;;
    listPointer->size = 2*(list->size);

    free(*(list->array)); // How to free  list pointer and its members?

  }else if(opType == HALF_THE_LIST){

    accumulator = malloc(((list->size)/2)*sizeof(void *));
    listPointer->array = &accumulator;

    /* Performing shallow copy, Is deep copy required? */
    listPointer->array = memcpy(listPointer->array, list->array, (list->size/2)*sizeof(void *));
    listPointer->lastItemPosition = list->lastItemPosition;
    listPointer->size = (list->size)/2;

    free(*(list->array)); // How to free  list pointer and its members?
  }

  return listPointer;

}
```

---

following list operations are performed `List`,

```
void insertItem(List *, void *newItem);
void deleteItem(List *, int listIndex);
```

User access,

```
/* main.c */

#include"list.h"

int main(void){
  List *arrayList = createList((List *)NULL, CREATE_NEW_LIST);


  if (arrayList == (List *)NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to createList() \n");
    exit(1); //Nothing else to do without arrayList
  }

  /* Objects should be on heap */
  int *object = malloc(sizeof(int));

  *object = 650;


  insertItem(arrayList, object);
}
```

---

Question:

Can you please clarify, what does free(*(list->array)) does in my code?

Comment: why cant you use free?

Comment: Encapsulation aspect is taken care. Please ignore that. Full code [here](https://github.com/shamhub/Computing/tree/master/2_List/Implementation_C). `linkedListImpl.c` is yet to be taken care

Comment: @pm100 Not sure, how to use `free` in this situation? Because am doing a shallow copy to enhance/half the list

Comment: You free a pointer with `free(ptr)`. `free()` only frees the memory at the memory location given. If the memory location contains pointers, then you need to free each one them first.

Comment: @MarkLakata If I free `pointer1` pointing to an `object`, does it effect `pointer2` pointing to same `object`? Because sometime testing such thing is tough.

Comment: Yes, it affects it. Don't free an object that is referenced by another pointer, otherwise your program will crash with a segmentation fault if you are lucky.  For testing purposes, you need to be careful about what *creates* the data objects, and what *reads* the data object. Reading a data object should NEVER free it. And the creator of the object needs to keep it alive until all readers are done reading it. This is just the way it is in software, nothing is easy.

Comment: @MarkLakata So, how do I free pointers pointing in `list->array` because `listPointer->array` is also pointing after shallow copy[`memcpy(listPointer->array, list->array, list->size*sizeof(void*));`]. Did you get my problem?

Comment: You can't free it. Why do you want to free it? If `listPointer`owns it, then you can't take it away from listPointer.

Comment: why not use realloc, which handles both adaption of memory size and - if necessary - (shallow) copying the previous memory block to a new one?

Comment: @MarkLakata Am I not wasting memory of `list->array` pointers, which is not required?

Comment: @StephanLechner Yes, that is a better idea instead of wasting memory.

Comment: I think you need to learn more about pointers. The fact that you did this `accumulator = malloc(INITIAL_LIST_SIZE*sizeof(void*));    listPointer->array = &accumulator;` shows that you don't have an understanding of pointers and the heap model of C (your use of `&accumulator`is wrong), and it will take more than a few comments to sort you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code snipped should do the job:

```c
else if(opType == DOUBLE_THE_LIST){

    listPointer->array = realloc(listPointer->array, 2*(list->size)*sizeof(void *));

    listPointer->lastItemPosition = list->lastItemPosition;;
    listPointer->size = 2*(list->size);

    // do not free any more: free(*(list->array)); // How to free  list pointer and its members?
}
```

Comment: Can you also add the consequences of doing shallow copy and `free(*(list->array));`, that is happening in current code?

Comment: as list->array is a pointer to an array of pointers, *(list->array) means the same as list->array[0]; Hence, free(*(list->array)) frees the memory assigned to the first element in list->array (if any)

Comment: Do you need two arguments in `realloc`?

Comment: ahh - yes, you are right. the original pointer, and the new size

Answer (score 0):

For option `DOUBLE_THE_LIST` and option `HALF_THE_LIST` your code is called with an existing `list`.

The code then creates a new list and copies either the whole or the half of the existing list into the new list.

Then the existing list is deleted (aka free'd) using `free(*(list->array));`

Finally the new list is returned using `return listPointer;`

So when using the function with these option, you should always do the assignment of the return value to the same list as you use as argument. That is:

```
myList = createList(myList, HALF_THE_LIST);
```

If you do:

```
myListB = createList(myListA, HALF_THE_LIST);
```

you'll `myListA`pointing to already free'd memory which is bad.